# File iteration. Can't use float object in for loop

Tags: python, file, sum, average

```
 def main():
        printIntro() # prints into for user
        diveline = processDives() # calls function to read a file
    
    
    def printIntro():
        print("Welcome to the Diver Scoring program. This program will calculate an \n overall score for a diver, based on individual dives.")
        #prints intro for user
    
    def processDives():
        file_object = open("DiveData.txt", 'r') #opens desired file in read mode
        diveline = file_object.readlines() #reads the line of the file and develops it into a string
        for line in diveline: #iterates through each line in diveline
            calculateDiveScore(line) # calls function to find calculations for dive scores
        print("\nThe average score for these dives is") #prints the average for scores
            
    
    def calculateDiveScore(diveline):
        diveline = diveline.split()
        diveNum = int(diveline[0]) #defines variable for dive number for each dive
        difficulty = float(diveline[1]) #defines variable for difficulty for each dive
        scoreList = diveline[2:] # defines variables to create score list for each dive
        scoreList.remove(max(scoreList)) #removes max value from scoreList
        scoreList.remove(min(scoreList)) #removes min value from scoreList
        sumscoreList = sum(float(i) for i in scoreList) # finds the sum of scoreList
        finalScore = (sumscoreList * difficulty) *.6 # multiplies difficulty and .6 to find the final value for the diver's scores
        print("\nThe diver's score for dive", diveNum, "is", "{0:.2f}".format(finalScore)) # outputs info for user to see which dive has which score
        for i in finalScore:
print(sum(i))

           
    main() #calls main to operate first
```

This program iterates through number values on a text file to find the scores for multiple dives. I am attempting to find the average score for all dives. The values that I am trying to find the average of are represented by the variable "finalScore". I try to iterate through the values within a for loop however I am given a type error stating that float object is not iterable. How else can I find the sum and average of these values under finalScore?

This is the content of the text file that I am using for this program.

> 1 3.5 5.5 6.0 7.0 6.5 6.5 5.5 7.5
>
> 2 2.0 8.0 8.5 8.5 9.0 8.0 8.5 8.0

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your `finalScore` seems to be a scalar rather than a list, how are you supposed to iterate through it?

Comment: If I cannot iterate through the values of finalScore, how else can I find the sum of the values that are represented by it?

Comment: It might be helpful to simply edit your code above down to the little loop that is causing a problem.  On StackOverflow you want the minimal viable code, we don't need to read through printIntro, main(), etc.  It will be more likely somebody will help you out vs just pasting the whole script in.

Comment: I was hoping that someone would test the code for themselves to better understand the issue that I am having.

Comment: `finakScore` is a `float` not a list. You cannot iterate over a float.

Comment: I am looking for the proper way to sum the items that are the values for finalScore. I understand that you cannot iterate through a float, I have that explained in my question.

Comment: **there are no values in finalScore** it is a **single value**. Even if it was a list, your proposed for -loop doesn't make any sense. I don't think you fundamentally understand what the `sum` function does

Answer (score 0):

```
sumscoreList = sum(float(i) for i in scoreList)
```

Here, `sum()` does NOT create an iterable. It simply sums up the values supplied to it and returns a **value**. The name is also misleading as it suggests that the variable is a list.